# Is it possible to intall the opengeostack and QGIS nightly?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, installation, ubuntu, boundless-suite

Did someone managed to get the opengeostack running alongside qgis so the plugin suite-qgis-plugin can be used?
I am trying it on ubuntu1304, installing opengeostack works ok, but then when installing qgis-nightly, i get an error:

> dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libgdal1_1.9.0-3.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>   trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libgdal.so.1', which is also in package libgdal 1.9.1-1
>
> dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/gdal-bin_1.9.0-3.1ubuntu1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
>   trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/ogrtindex', which is also in package libgdal 1.9.1-1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a conflict in gdal versions used by opengeo packages vs the qgis packages. I am going to file an issue for this to try and address for the next version of the opengeo packages.

If you don't require postgis as part of the installation you can install the opengeo-geoserver package directly. This won't install the version of gdal that conflicts with qgis. You'll first have to back out the libgdal that was installed with opengeo as alexgleith mentions, as well as everything downstream of it.

Comment: Wondering what will happen with the new Boundless distribution with qgis included...

Answer (score 0):

This is a package management error.

Try removing one of the packages for libgdal.

Something like 'sudo apt-get remove libgdal-1.9.1-1' (type it all to 'lib' then hit tab to autocomplete).